# Unusual nesting of table, table-row and table-cell

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to convert several nested divs (like below) into a CSS table structure with the display styles of table, table-row and table-cell. This works fine. But there are some other elements in the DOM structure (identified below by classes "red" and "blue") which I cannot remove but I don't need them for the appearance on the screen. If I leave these elements in the DOM tree, the table structure doesn't display correctly. Is there any possibility to let them in the DOM tree but ignore them on display?

```
<div style="display: table">
  <div class="blue">
    <div style="display: table-row">
      <div class="red">
        <div style="display: table-cell">
          ...
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
      <div class="red">
        <div style="display: table-cell">
          ...
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

why would you like to reinvent the wheel ? if you want to use `table` just do it, don't pretend you are not using table by implementing it on your own with `divs`. You are not gaining anything, only wasting your time.

The only scenario I can imagine is that you do not have access to HTML - otherwise why you cannot remove these divs .red and .blue?

Now targeting your real question. You obviously cannot add to .red and .blue `display: none` nor `visibility: hidden`, but you might try `display: inline;`. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: I think you are right, but in fact I don't have access to the HTML. the HTML is like it is, but I would like it to layout like a table. It would help a bit if I could tell any HTML element to be ignored. Setting it to "display=none" or "visibility=hidden" make the whole element including all children disappear. "display=inline" also doesn't solve the problem. Maybe this problem is not possible to solve.?

Comment: Well the only idea that comes to my mind, which is very UGLY one, is to use javascript and remove .red and .blue and hope for the best. Nothing else comes to my mind

Comment: `why would you like to reinvent the wheel ?` Because there is responsive design concern.